# Memory leak (?) using IO::Socket::Async (on FreeBSD 13.1)

Tags: sockets, memory-leaks, raku

In processing a stream of logs (via UDP) in a raku (v2022.07) app, I'm
hitting what appears to be a memory leak using IO::Socket::Async.
I pulled the code out into a simpler program which I've included below
(~ identical to code at https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Socket::Async):

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku
#
my $socket = IO::Socket::Async.bind-udp('localhost', 24225);
react {
    whenever $socket.Supply -> $v {
        print $v if $v.chars > 0;
    };
};
```

It leaks substantial ram - I let it run about 12 hours and
when I checked  --  still running (on a 1T ram machine) -- with
ps auwwx [pid]

it showed 314974456 and 20739784 for VSZ and RSS (so, roughly 300G v size and 20G resident).

[btw, the UDP traffic is fairly light - average of 350 (~100 byte) packets/sec (spikes to ~1000/sec)]

So ..  I rewrote above in perl5 (after similar leaky results w/
a couple of raku variants) which stabilizes quickly at about 8M resident - that's fine/stable/etc. -
but I'd prefer this process to feed a raku channel (without separate perl process/file
tailing, etc.).

My environment:  FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE-p2 GENERIC amd64 and raku:
v2022.07 built on MoarVM 2022.07 (installed with rakubrew).

I'm guessing this is unique to raku on freebsd but not sure.

I did attempt to upgrade (rakubrew) to v2022.12 to see if problem resolved there -
but in rebuilding modules (zef), too many failed (some issue with
Digest/Digest::HMAC) - so I had to revert to 2022.07.

I'll sure be grateful for any suggestions for addressing the leak or alternative
methods to address reading from a UDP port.

Comment: You should make an issue on Rakudo, Stack Overflow is for questions not really for suggestions like this I think. This is most likely a bug.

Comment: Hi @wingfold. Did you make any progress?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a solution to your problem, but you can monitor memory usage from within your Raku code using built-in feature:

```
use Telemetry;
say T{"max-rss"};
```

Also remember that Supply by default decodes unicode chars. If your protocol is binary you may add `:bin` to Socket params to avoid treating binary data as text.